# Why does INTMAX_MAX give wrong result here?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

I came across a problem which asked me to find the maximum of the cheapest paths between any given pair of vertices. I implemented Floyd Warshall algorithm for the solution. But there is one weird error in my program. I'm using intmax_t to avoid overflows, but if I use INTMAX_MAX instead of INT_MAX for infinite cost to denote that two vertices are not connected directly, I get the wrong answer. Why is this happening?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct _ { ios_base::Init _i; _() { cin.sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); } } _;

#define endl '\n'
#define int intmax_t
#define in(x) for (auto& i: x)
#define test int _t; cin >> _t; for (int i=1; i<=_t; i++) {

signed main()
{
    int v, e, ans=INT_MIN;
    cin >> v >> e;
    int g[v+1][v+1];
    for (int i=1; i<=v; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=v; j++)
            g[i][j]=INT_MAX;
    for (int i=0; i<e; i++)
    {
        int x, y, p;
        cin >> x >> y >> p;
        g[x][y]=g[y][x]=p;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=v; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=v; j++)
            for (int k=1; k<=v; k++)
                g[j][k]=min(g[j][k], g[j][i]+g[i][k]);
    for (int i=1; i<=v; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=v; j++)
            if (g[i][j]!=INT_MAX && i!=j)
                ans=max(ans, g[i][j]);
    cout << ans;
}
```

If I replace INT_MIN by INTMAX_MIN and INT_MAX by INTMAX_MAX, I get incorrect result.

Sample cases:

Using INT_MAX: http://ideone.com/ffmv7P

Using INTMAX_MAX: http://ideone.com/vjMCuE

Addendum: This program was specifically written for the purpose of solving a competitive programming problem. Please keep your "correct coding practice" advice to yourself. If you are willing to answer, you will find that the preprocessor directives cause little or no problem with readability in this case. They are there for a reason, I am not stupid. If you have no competitive programming experience, do not place the blame on me. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think INTMAX_MAX +  INTMAX_MAX is? Also, seriously, clean up those disgusting macros.

Comment: Well now I have seen `signed main()` too...

Comment: Oh, thanks. I should have chosen the infinite value carefully. About the "disgusting macros", there's only one macro, and why is it disgusting? This is a competitive programming problem and the `in` macro does come in handy at times to save time. My question isn't even about that, and it does not affect what I've asked. signed is to compensate for the intmax_t directive.

Comment: `#define int intmax_t` -- I strongly advise against doing that. Use a `typedef`, not a macro, and give it a name other than `int`.

Comment: First `using namespace std;` then `#define endl '\n'`... Really? Why?

Comment: I'm amazed that there are 2 answers. Apparently there are people who are far more willing to wade through this mud than I am.

Comment: Get out of here, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding numbers and having the possibility for overflow. When using `INT_MAX` you're initializing the cells with a number that's possibly lower than the range of `intmax_t` (which is the real type of the cells). That is `INT_MAX+INT_MAX` is likely to fit into `intmax_t` without overflow while `INTMAX_MAX+INTMAX_MAX` definitely don't.

You run into integer overflow which in theory has undefined behaviour. Most probably in reality it will not work well together with comparison since integer overflow will wrap to negative numbers making `INTMAX_MAX+INTMAX_MAX` much less than `INTMAX_MAX` (it can even become negative).

If you had a compiler where `int` has the same range `intmax_t` (which is not that unrealistic) your code should fail in both cases.

Comment: I have been doing this `g[v+1]` type allocation for a long time now. Never came across any unexpected behavior on online judges. The problem here is just that `INTMAX_MAX+INTMAX_MAX` by definition is greater than the maximum value that intmax_t can store, right?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan  The problem with `g[v+1]` is when `v` is uninitialized, when `v` is negative (or perhaps with older version of the language). Perhaps you've not been using uninitialized values before? The uninitialized variable should be a real concern, consider what happens if `v` happens to be negative, too large (for the memory) or not large enough (for the `x`s and `y`s). So it's not just the `INTMAX_MAX+INTMAX_MAX` that's a (potential) problem here.

Comment: Okay, any idea why this has never happened with me? crashing of a program when the uninitialized value of v is negative.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Sorry, my mistake. `v` is not uninitalized as you read it from `cin`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously not store an INTMAX_MAX in a variable of type int. You get an overflow, which leads to undefined behaviour. In practice, you will often get the last 32 bits of the INTMAX_MAX, which are the same bit pattern as (int) -1.

On the other hand, comparing an int with INTMAX_MAX means the int will be converted to intmax_t, but as long as the types are different (which they are in practice), an int will never, ever be equal to INTMAX_MAX.

Comment: it's possible to store `INTMAX_MAX` in an int if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(intmax_t)`, although probably no compiler will implement like that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It's not that unlikely that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(intmax_t)`. For example on ILP64 or SILP64 systems it would be quite likely, according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) there are such architectures.